# Polymer 2.0: how to access a composant by its id?

Tags: polymer

I've transformed my code from Polymer 1.0 (works in 1.0).

Now, console reports only null or error during access to iron-element by its id. I don't understand why. Can you help me?

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="my-ajax">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax
            id="req"
            method="{{method}}"
            url="{{url}}"
            handle-as="{{returnType}}"
            content-type="{{contentType}}"
            params="{{queryString}}"
            on-response="_handleResponse"
            on-error="_handleError">
    </iron-ajax>
  </template>
  <script>
    class MyAjax extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'my-ajax'
        }
        static get properties() {
            return {
                method: {
                    type: String,
                    value: "GET",
                    notify: true
                },
                ...
               datas: {
                    type: Object,
                    notify: true
                }
            }
        }
        constructor() {
            super();
        }
        ready() {
            console.log(document.querySelector('#req'))
            console.log(document.querySelector('req'))
            console.log(this.$.req)
        }
        ...

    }
    customElements.define(MyAjax.is, MyAjax)
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

In 1.0 I intensively use `this.$.xxx` to access element without problems.

Answer (score 1):

When overriding any of the [lifecycle callbacks](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#lifecycle-callbacks) (including `ready()`), be sure to call the `super` equivalent. In this case, you need to call [`super.ready()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#ready-time) to properly setup automatic node binding.

```
ready() {
  super.ready();  // <-- required
  console.log(this.$.req);
}
```

Comment: Actually, in a method where I have to act with the iron-ajax element (id req) I have access to 'req' when I code  a super.ready () before; I confess that I am completely lost even after reading the DOM management in 2.0! Really, I don't see how I'll migrate all my code ! Many thanks

Comment: The code above log an undefined with Firefox (with webcomponents-lite.js)